# java xpath text

Tags: java, xpath

I'm kind of stuck with XPath and/or Java. I have XML document structures like the following:

```
<document>
  <text>
    <headline>This is the text's headline</headline>
    This is the text.
  </text>
 </document>
```

What I need is this:

```
<document>
  <text>
    <headline>This is the text's headline</headline>
    <w>This</w>
    <w>is</w>
    <w>the</w>
    <w>text</w>
    <w>.</w>
  </text>
 </document>
```

How in the world can I change the text content of the text-node while leaving the headline-node untouched?! (I'm using org.jdom2.xpath.)

Bob

Comment: You're looking to make a structural change to the read XML. I believe you'll need some XSL(T) to accomplish that - XPath is mostly for querying XML. For example, see the [<xsl:element>](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_element.asp) XSL tag for the creation of new elements in the output XML. Alternatively you could XPath select "This is the text.", break that up in Java, reassemble it using JDOM, then output the desired XML.

Comment: I'm not sure about the second part of your reply. My problem isn't breaking up "This is the text.", but keeping the headline-node in place.

Comment: XPath is for selecting XML nodes and computing things about those nodes. See the first two lines of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath. You can't create those `<w>` nodes in XPath.

Comment: Xpath is a *query* language for XML documents -- it cannot alter an XML document (create or delete nodes). XSLT is a language expecially created for XML transformation. Task like yours are trivial to solve with XSLT. If you want an XSLT solution, please indicate this.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the replies. I have to admit that XSLT's totally new to me. My idea (which obvisouly doesn't work) was this:
`node.setText(""); 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
          Element child = new Element("w");
          child.setText(words.get(i)); 
          
          node.addContent(child); }` However, this will also delete the headline-node (which I don't quite understand). If anybody can help me with XSLT, I'd greatly appreciate.

Comment: Well, forget about the "which I don't quite understand" part. Obviously, this is the supposed behavior of setText(), see [here](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/issues/85). The problem remains, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to clear the text content of `<text>` and setting (empty) text removes all other content, you could clone the `<headline>` element first and add it back after using `setText()`. Then continue into your loop and create the `<w>` elements.

As for XPath, you can select the `<heading>` element with

```
/document/text/heading
```

and the text content of the `<text>` element with

```
/document/text/text()
```